# Create doc in Doc Library with fields prepopulated

Tags: list, document-library, document-template, download

We are trying to accomplish this... From a page in a site, the user selects a value that is offered in a drop down based on who the user is in the organization.

This drop down is in place already and shows the values from which the user can choose.

When the user makes that choice, we update 5 other computed fields.

Furthermore, we found out how to programmatically create a document library with a content type defined with fields for the choice the user made plus the 5 computed fields.

This is the only part I can't seem to find:

How can I create a Word doc from the library (based on the library template) with those 6 fields already populated? BTW, this document creation should happen on the click of a button.

I would like to do this with CodeBehind.

Thanks!
E

Comment: Is the fields added to the doc itself? If I am assuming correctly, You want to download the item you just created on the click of the button!

Comment: Taran, that is correct. Once added to the library, I was going to issue a redirect to the url of the doc. The fields should be in the doc on download.

Comment: are you using client side object model or server side model to create the doc? And does the document get created on the click of button?

Comment: Yes, the doc should get created at the click of a button (which is already implemented). Right now the button redirects to some other place. I think I would prefer to do this server side.

Comment: When you create a doc, you already have ID of the doc. Why don't you construct a URL with the help of it and redirect the user? Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Yikes. I re-read what I wrote and it wasn't clear what I am after. Sorry for the trouble I caused you. :(

Comment: Ohh..so you want to create a document based on the template? If that's the case are there some fields in the template(inside the word doc) which you want to replace with the computed ones? Also do you want to store this in the library? sorry for so many questions I just want to understand the situation.

Comment: I appreciate your questions. Yeah, the fields in the document need to be populated with the computed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will create and update a document:

```
public void UpdateAndCreateFile(SPWeb web)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    string TemplateUrl = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        TemplateUrl = "Your Document templated full path";
                    }
                    catch { }


                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList olist = web.Lists["Document Library"];
                    String url = olist.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();


                    string foldername = Convert.ToString("Foldername in document library");
                    SPFolder newfolder = web.GetFolder(url + "/" + foldername);

                    if (!newfolder.Exists)
                    {
                        SPFolderCollection folders = web.GetFolder(url).SubFolders;
                        //Create new folder
                        folders.Add(foldername);
                    }

                    SPFile file = null;

                    file = web.GetFile("Your Document templated full path");

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        Stream readStream = file.OpenBinaryStream(); //file is SPFile type
                        SPFile uploadedFile = newfolder.Files.Add(newfolder.Url + @"/" + "NewDocName.docx", readStream, true);
                        uploadedFile.CheckOut();
                        SPListItem listitem = uploadedFile.Item;
                        // Details is mapped in document
                        listitem["Details"] = "this content will added in document";
//You can refer more columns here to update. Or even replace the content by reading the file.
                        listitem.Update();
                        uploadedFile.Update();
                        uploadedFile.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                });






            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle exception here
            }

        }
```

below couple of links which helps you :

- [Programmatically upload a document in document library](http://somnathmatere.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-programmatically-upload-document.html)
- [Upload document programmatically](http://www.sharepointbleached.com/2012/04/upload-document-programmatically.html)
- [Using Document Templates with Lists and Content Types](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/02/using-document-templates-with-lists-and-content-types-in-sharepoint/)
- [Pull SharePoint 2010 document properties into Word](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/pull-sharepoint-2010-document-properties-into-word-quick-parts/)

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/57159/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly there are 5 metedata,columns that automatically created when the word document is created. In your word template on the insert tab, go to the "Quick Parts" and select document properties. If those fields are attached to your content type you should see them there. Add them to your Word Document template wherever you want then to be displayed.. Hope this helps.